# Python Scrapy dictionary project

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping, scrapy

Is it possible to make a Python Scrapy spider that crawls an entire website, creates a dictionary that contains every word used in the website in one column, and also shows the URLs of all the instances of each word in the column next to it? If yes, how?

I assume that the spider should continuously scrape each URL, turn the HTML into plain text, then divide each string into list items, create a list, and then only add items to that list that haven't been added before. But, at the same time, it should also know which items already have been added to the list and their position, and when it scrapes a word identical to one already on the list, remember it's URL and add it to the column with the URLs.

I already created a spider (see below) that makes a list of all the URLs and all the plain text found at each URL, but my programming skills are not good enough to figure out how to continue from here, make Python jump over the data/words already scraped, and make it into a dictionary. Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from digital.items import DataItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class SampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('blog', 'catalogsearch', 'review')),
             callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=DataItem(), response=response)
        l.add_value('link', response.url)
        l.add_xpath('text', '//*[not(self::script)]/text()')
        return l.load_item()
```

And my items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from w3lib.html import remove_tags


def remove_whitespace(value):
    return value.strip()


class DataItem(scrapy.Item):
    link = scrapy.Field()
    text = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_whitespace),
        output_processor=Join()
    )
```

Comment: This seems rather broad in scope.

Comment: How could I narrow it down? Maybe first ask how Python and Scrapy can turn the plain text into a list without redundant words?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to split the work in two parts: extraction and post-processing.

You use Scrapy to extract items with two fields: `word` and `url`. I would export the results as a JSON Lines file.

Then, you use a regular Python script to turn the resulting JSON Lines file from Scrapy into the desired result, removing duplicates and merging items by `word`, combining their `url`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using an [Item Pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class DictionaryPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, category_count):
        self.dictionary = defaultdict(list)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # get all unique words from text
        unique_words = {word for words in item['text'] for word in words.split()}

        # insert/update dictionary
        url = item['url']
        for word in unique_words:
            self.dictionary[word].append(url)

        return item
```

Note that this will consume a lot of memory. You're probably better off separating the logic (as Gallaecio suggested), and use something like map-reduce (similar to [this](https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) approach) to get your final result. You can also still consider using the Item Pipeline, but use a database to persist the data instead of keeping the dictionary in memory.